# Remove text before a character but also remove that character

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a string path as follows;

```
New Folder/New Folder 2/test22.js
```

I only want the text after the first forward slash, e.g.;

```
    New Folder 2/test22.js
```

I tried this;

```
myText.substring(myText.indexOf('/'))
```

But I get this.  Note the forward slash is still shown.

```
/New Folder 2/test22.js
```

This sounds like a simple request but cannot get my head around it.

**EDIT**
Got it working as follows but not sure if this is the best way to go about it;

```
myText.split(/\/(.+)/)[1]
```

Comment: Your first solution works well, but remember the 0-based, so add 1 to it `myText.substring(myText.indexOf('/') + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add 1 to the index the substring is being applied to i.e. `myText.substring(myText.indexOf('/') + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by using a simple split and join.

```
x = "New Folder/New Folder 2/test22.js";
x = x.split('/').slice(1).join('/'); // required string.
```

here,

1. split('/') will convert it to ["New Folder", "New Folder 2", "test22.js"]
2. slice(1) to get elements after first element
3. join('/') to get the required string.

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

instead of split and join again, you can search immediately only for the first one

```
const matches = /.*?\/(.+)/.exec("New Folder/New Folder 2/test22.js");
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a substring as below

```
let myPath = 'New Folder/New Folder 2/test22.js';
let resultPath = myPath.substring(myPath.indexOf('/'));
```